# Toast notification for winget upgrade

Tags: powershell, notifications, winget

Could I send a notification of the amount of upgrades available for the winget package manager.

Plan somehow get int variable of available amount post to toast.

Possibly using

https://github.com/Windos/BurntToast

```
New-BurntToastNotification -Text "int Updates Available"
```